# Show that $P(A)=\sum_{k \in A}p(1-p)^{k-1},p \in(0,1)$ defines a probability over the Borel field of events $(\Omega,K)$

Tags: probability

$\Omega=N^*,K=P(\Omega)$. Show that $P(A)=\sum_{k \in A}p(1-p)^{k-1},p \in(0,1)$ defines a probability over the Borel field of events $(\Omega,K)$.(I hope this is translated ok)
$E_1=\{n\in N|n>5\}, E_2=\{n\in N|n<7\}, E_3=\{n\in N|3\le n \le 6\}$. Calculate $P(E_1),P(E_2),P(E_3),P(E_1\cap E_2),P(E_1 \cup E_2),P(E_1|E_3)$.

How I think this is solved:
$p\sum_{n>0}(1-p)^{n-1}$
$P(E_1)=1-p[1+(1-p)+(1-p)^2+(1-p)^3]$
$P(E_2)=p[1+(1-p)+(1-p)^2+(1-p)^3+(1-p)^4+(1-p)^5]$
$P(E_3)=p[(1-p)^2+(1-p)^3+(1-p)^4+(1-p)^5]$
Is this correct? Also how do I solve the other 3? $P(E_1\cap E_2),P(E_1 \cup E_2),P(E_1|E_3)$
Thanks!

Comment: Work out what the events were? Also you cans simplify the first 3 by geometric distribution formula.